# Storing integers values from file into a vectors of vector

Tags: c++

I'm trying to store into a vector integer values from a file.
Each line of the file contains three values, so i'm trying to create a vector of vectors, each one containing three values.

```
vector< vector<int> > links;

ifstream infile("my_file");

int a, b, c;
int i = 0;
while (infile >> a >> b >> c)
{
    links[i].push_back(a);
    links[i].push_back(b);
    links[i].push_back(c);
    i++;
}
```

Actually gave this error after compiling: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)

Comment: The [] operator cannot be used to insert new elements to a vector. You need to create a new `vector<int>` on each iteration before pushing values into it.

Comment: @E_net4 Please use the _answer_ feature/section for providing answers.

Comment: if each element of the outer vector always consists of 3 ints, then you should maybe use a `struct foo{ int a,b,c;};` rather than a vector

Comment: @Lightness I'll pass. There is likely a good duplicate for this one anyway.

Comment: @E_net4 Then you can simply omit an answer but if you do provide one please don't do it in the comments; we can't peer review it there. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 3):

Each iteration of your loop needs to do two things:

1. create a new *inner* vector in `links`
2. add the three elements to the newly created inner vector

Your example tries to do 2) without 1). You could potentially avoid 1) if you knew the size of your file (number of lines) and resize `links` to the correct size before you enter the loop.

Otherwise you have to do both tasks, along the lines of

```
while (...)
{
#if 0
    // create new inner vector (C++17 version)
    auto& inner = links.emplace_back();
#else
    // create new inner vector (C++11 version)
    links.emplace_back();
    auto& inner = links.back();
#endif

    // insert elements
    inner.push_back(a);
    inner.push_back(b);
    inner.push_back(c);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm trying in this way, but have another error: Cannot form a reference to 'void'

Comment: you are using and older compiler then, previously `emplace_back` had a `void` return type, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back - I've edited the anwser